# How do I use URL forwarding to a specific webpage on the target domain?

Tags: html, .htaccess

I am learning to forward URLs, and am not sure if I am using the proper terminology.  Here's what I've done so far and what I'm trying to accomplish. I created a website "ABC.com".  I got a free domain from freenom.com called "XYZ.cf".  Freenom lets me "forward" anyone visiting XYZ.cf to my website ABC.com.

By default, anyone who types in XYZ.cf will be forwarded to the index.htm file of my ABC.com website.  I'd like to be able to give people this URL: "XYZ.cf/special1.htm" and they will be able to access the special1.htm on my ABC.com website.  And it's not just special1.htm, but any file where it looks like "XYZ.cf/variable.htm" will be redirected to my ABC.com/variable.htm where variable will be ANY filename.

For example:

```
If I give people the url XYZ.cf/1.htm, they should end up at ABC.com/1.htm.
If I give people the url XYZ.cf/2.htm, they should end up at ABC.com/2.htm.
If I give people the url XYZ.cf/3.htm, they should end up at ABC.com/3.htm.
If I give people the url XYZ.cf/4.htm, they should end up at ABC.com/4.htm.
If I give people the url XYZ.cf/5.htm, they should end up at ABC.com/5.htm.
If I give people the url XYZ.cf/6.htm, they should end up at ABC.com/6.htm.
If I give people the url XYZ.cf/7.htm, they should end up at ABC.com/7.htm.
```

I only have 7 of these files.  That's it.  What do I need to do?

Comment: If you're doing this for multiple URLs, you sould look at a server-side URL aliasing technology for this. Doing it in a file is going to be a lot of work as the site grows.

Comment: I think I want to do this for about 7 URLs.  That is, XYZ.cf/1.htm through XYZ.cf/7.htm should forward/redirect to ABC.com/1.htm through ABC.com/7.htm.  What's the easiest way to implement this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you should have a look at `mod_rewrite` and declare a rewrite rule in your `.htaccess` file.

More Information: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Answer (score 0):

Add this code to the head of the page you want to redirect.

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=INSERT URL YOU WANT TO REDIRECT TO HERE/" />
```

Comment: Thank you, I reworded my question to be more precise.  I don't want to redirect to just a single webpage.  I want to be able to redirect to whatever webpage the user typed.  For example, if the user typed in XYZ.cf/Tom.htm, it should really go to ABC.com/Tom.htm.  If the user typed in XYZ.cf/Bob.htm, it should go to ABC.com/Bob.htm.  Let's just assume that both Tom.htm and Bob.htm already exists on the ABC.com domain

Answer (score 0):

In file .htaccess, just add:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !ABC.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://ABC. com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thank you, I reworded my question to be more precise.  I want to be able to hand out any variable.htm filename and have the user get directed to it at ABC.com/variable.htm.  So, I don't want to just redirect to special.htm only.

Comment: So where you define variable.

Comment: I don't understand your question.  Perhaps this example might help illuminate what I'm trying to do.  XYZ.cf/1.htm through XYZ.cf/7.htm should forward/redirect to ABC.com/1.htm through ABC.com/7.htm. What's the easiest way to implement this?

Comment: Do you have rule about it? which page will be redirected to which page?

Comment: If user types in XYZ.cf/foobar.htm it will go to ABC.com/foobar.htm.  If user types in XYZ.cf/jewel.htm it will go to ABC.com/jewel.htm.  If user types in XYZ.cf/nguyen.htm it will go to ABC.com/nguyen.htm.  I have about 7 of these files that I want to do.  And I don't know how to do it.

Comment: I spent some time trying to understand your above code and learning about .htaccess.  Does the forwarding domain need to do anything special to make the code work?  Right now XYZ.cf simply forwards to ABC.com.  Is that all that is needed for the above .htaccess code to work?